# How to have a unique date with following code?

Tags: c#

Need help with having unique date insert!

Having trouble executing code.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string a = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("");

if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSal.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt13.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmp.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPark.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBank.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMisc.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTrans.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLight.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOS.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOE.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPagibig.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSSS.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPHIL.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRent.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTL.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTele.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTravel.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRM.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtICRT.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lbltotal.Text)))
    {
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jaey\Documents\Transaction.accdb");
    OleDbCommand dt;
    con.Open();
    dt = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Expenses ([Date], Salaries, [13th], Employee, Parking, Bank, Misc, Transpo, Light, [Office supply], [Office Equipment], Pagibig, SSS, Philhealth, Rental, Tax, Tel, Travel, Repairs, I, Total)  VALUES   ('" + a + "','" + txtSal.Text + "','" + txt13.Text + "','" + txtEmp.Text + "','" + txtPark.Text + "','" + txtBank.Text + "','" + txtMisc.Text + "','" + txtTrans.Text + "','" + txtLight.Text + "','" + txtOS.Text + "',' " + txtOE.Text + "','" + txtPagibig.Text + "','" + txtSSS.Text + "','" + txtPHIL.Text + "','" + txtRent.Text + "','" + txtTL.Text + "','" + txtTele.Text + "','" + txtTravel.Text + "','" + txtRM.Text + "','" + txtICRT.Text + "', '" + lbltotal.Text + "')", con);
    dt.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
}
```

How can I insert unique date value ?
Is the data validation right ?

Comment: I don't know. Try it.

Comment: because it gives me an error which is Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression. please help me debugging this :(( I'm a newbie

Comment: if i enter a value in every text, my data would save but if i enter just 1 value in 1 textbox it gives me error..

Comment: If it gives you an error - then no, it's not valid. And if you want help for a particular error, you should include the error message as well.

Comment: What happens when one of the other textboxes is not empty? It will go the `else` statement for sure. Mixing empty and not empty values.

Comment: I would suggest that prior to saving your data to the database, validate each field first, being it required or optional. Required values should have messages that will alert the user to be informed on what s/he needs to enter. While optional values are the ones you will have each field a default value. After that you can put each field into your SQL.

Comment: maybe i will code it one by one :((

Comment: i am using ms access :((

Comment: i just put 0 each textbox so database would accept it if the user just enter 1 data value LOL

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use SQL parameters to insert data. By doing this you can also ensure that the datatypes are correct.

Comment: Also, you need to perform data validation before you attempt inserting data.

Comment: i dont know what parameter is hihi and i think it would make my code much longer xD im a lazy pero LOL Kiddin, maybe next time im gonna study that parameters xD THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your problem in the comments. maybe next time include your problem in your question.

Maybe this is what you want? because you are having problems whit the statement where you check the values of the controls.

Refine you code like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string a = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("");


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSal.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt13.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmp.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPark.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBank.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMisc.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTrans.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLight.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOS.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOE.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPagibig.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSSS.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPHIL.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRent.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTL.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTele.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTravel.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRM.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtICRT.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lbltotal.Text))
    {


        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jaey\Documents\Transaction.accdb");
        OleDbCommand dt;
        con.Open();
        dt = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Expenses ([Date], Salaries, [13th], Employee, Parking, Bank, Misc, Transpo, Light, [Office supply], [Office Equipment], Pagibig, SSS, Philhealth, Rental, Tax, Tel, Travel, Repairs, I, Total)  VALUES   ('" + a + "','" + txtSal.Text + "','" + txt13.Text + "','" + txtEmp.Text + "','" + txtPark.Text + "','" + txtBank.Text + "','" + txtMisc.Text + "','" + txtTrans.Text + "','" + txtLight.Text + "','" + txtOS.Text + "',' " + txtOE.Text + "','" + txtPagibig.Text + "','" + txtSSS.Text + "','" + txtPHIL.Text + "','" + txtRent.Text + "','" + txtTL.Text + "','" + txtTele.Text + "','" + txtTravel.Text + "','" + txtRM.Text + "','" + txtICRT.Text + "', '" + lbltotal.Text + "')", con);
        dt.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
    }
```

This would require you to input all controls before inserting to database.

And maybe your having the error because in your MS DB you have a column where you don't accept Null values. And like you said, the error occurs when only 1 textbox is inputed which goes to the else statement and insert to the database.

Comment: thank you sir, im gonna need this someday :)) the ! is the key xDD